# Can't use runFormPost in Yesod Email Authentication's apLogin

Tags: yesod, yesod-forms

I'm trying to write an apLogin for Yesod's Email Authentication plugin and form helpers are throwing a type error. The loginForm can't be read by  runFormPost. I've tried several different combinations of type signatures, but this error message seems the clearest. It seems like I have the wrong top-level constraint, or that I'm missing one. What is the best way to set this up so that the proper types can be inferred?

```
authEmail :: (YesodAuthEmail m) => AuthPlugin m
authEmail =
    AuthPlugin "email" dispatch login
  where
    login toParent =
        toWidget $ do
            ((_,widget),enctype) <-  runFormPost loginForm
            [whamlet|
                <form method="post" action="@{toParent loginR}">
            |]
    loginForm extra = do
        let emailSettings = FieldSettings {
            fsLabel = SomeMessage Msg.Email,
            fsTooltip = Nothing,
            fsId = Just "email",
            fsName = Just "email",
            fsAttrs = [("autofocus", "")]
        }

        (emailRes, emailView) <- mreq emailField emailSettings Nothing

        let userRes = UserForm <$> emailRes
        let widget = do
            [whamlet|
                #{extra}
                ^{fvInput emailView}
            |]

        return (userRes, widget)
```

This is the error:

```
Could not deduce (MonadIO m0) arising from a use of ‘loginForm’
from the context (YesodAuthEmail m)
  bound by the type signature for
             authEmail :: YesodAuthEmail m => AuthPlugin m
  at Yesod/Auth/Email.hs:260:14-47
or from (MonadWidget m1, YesodAuth (HandlerSite m1))
  bound by the inferred type of
           login :: (MonadWidget m1, YesodAuth (HandlerSite m1)) =>
                    (AuthRoute -> Route (HandlerSite m1)) -> m1 ()
  at Yesod/Auth/Email.hs:(270,5)-(275,14)
The type variable ‘m0’ is ambiguous
Note: there are several potential instances:
  instance MonadIO m =>
           MonadIO
             (conduit-1.2.6.1:Data.Conduit.Internal.Conduit.ConduitM i o m)
    -- Defined in ‘conduit-1.2.6.1:Data.Conduit.Internal.Conduit’
  instance MonadIO m =>
           MonadIO (conduit-1.2.6.1:Data.Conduit.Internal.Pipe.Pipe l i o u m)
    -- Defined in ‘conduit-1.2.6.1:Data.Conduit.Internal.Pipe’
  instance MonadIO IO -- Defined in ‘Control.Monad.IO.Class’
  ...plus 18 others
In the first argument of ‘runFormPost’, namely ‘loginForm’
In a stmt of a 'do' block:
  ((_, widget), enctype) <- runFormPost loginForm
In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
  ‘do { ((_, widget), enctype) <- runFormPost loginForm;
        (do { (asWidgetT . toWidget)
                ((Text.Blaze.Internal.preEscapedText . T.pack)
                   "<form method=\"post\" action=\"");
              (getUrlRenderParams
               >>=
                 (\ urender_ajDM
                    -> (asWidgetT . toWidget)
                         (toHtml (\ u_ajDN -> urender_ajDM u_ajDN ... (toParent loginR)))));
              (asWidgetT . toWidget)
                ((Text.Blaze.Internal.preEscapedText . T.pack)
                   "\"></form>\n") }) }’
```

Code with handlerToWidget correction:

```
authEmail :: (YesodAuthEmail m) => AuthPlugin m
authEmail =
    AuthPlugin "email" dispatch login
where
    login toParent = do
            ((_,widget),enctype) <- handlerToWidget $ runFormPost loginForm
            [whamlet|
                <form method="post" action="@{toParent loginR}">
            |]
    loginForm extra = do
        let emailSettings = FieldSettings {
            fsLabel = SomeMessage Msg.Email,
            fsTooltip = Nothing,
            fsId = Just "email",
            fsName = Just "email",
            fsAttrs = [("autofocus", "")]
        }

        (emailRes, emailView) <- mreq emailField emailSettings Nothing

        let userRes = UserForm <$> emailRes
        let widget = do
            [whamlet|
                #{extra}
                ^{fvInput emailView}
            |]

        return (userRes, widget)
```

Error:

```
    Could not deduce (MonadIO m0) arising from a use of ‘loginForm’
    from the context (YesodAuthEmail m)
      bound by the type signature for
                 authEmail :: YesodAuthEmail m => AuthPlugin m
      at Yesod/Auth/Email.hs:260:14-47
    or from (MonadIO m1,
             MonadBaseControl IO m1,
             exceptions-0.8.2.1:Control.Monad.Catch.MonadThrow m1,
             YesodAuth site)
      bound by the inferred type of
               login :: (MonadIO m1, MonadBaseControl IO m1,
                         exceptions-0.8.2.1:Control.Monad.Catch.MonadThrow m1,
                         YesodAuth site) =>
                        (AuthRoute -> Route site) -> WidgetT site m1 ()
      at Yesod/Auth/Email.hs:(270,5)-(275,14)
    The type variable ‘m0’ is ambiguous
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance MonadIO m =>
               MonadIO
                 (conduit-1.2.6.1:Data.Conduit.Internal.Conduit.ConduitM i o m)
        -- Defined in ‘conduit-1.2.6.1:Data.Conduit.Internal.Conduit’
      instance MonadIO m =>
               MonadIO (conduit-1.2.6.1:Data.Conduit.Internal.Pipe.Pipe l i o u m)
        -- Defined in ‘conduit-1.2.6.1:Data.Conduit.Internal.Pipe’
      instance MonadIO IO -- Defined in ‘Control.Monad.IO.Class’
      ...plus 18 others
    In the first argument of ‘runFormPost’, namely ‘loginForm’
    In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘runFormPost loginForm’
    In a stmt of a 'do' block:
      ((_, widget), enctype) <- handlerToWidget $ runFormPost loginForm
```

Without toWidgetHandler error:

```
    Could not deduce (MonadIO m0) arising from a use of ‘loginForm’
    from the context (YesodAuthEmail m)
      bound by the type signature for
                 authEmail :: YesodAuthEmail m => AuthPlugin m
      at Yesod/Auth/Email.hs:260:14-47
    or from (MonadIO m1,
             MonadBaseControl IO m1,
             exceptions-0.8.2.1:Control.Monad.Catch.MonadThrow m1,
             YesodAuth site)
      bound by the inferred type of
               login :: (MonadIO m1, MonadBaseControl IO m1,
                         exceptions-0.8.2.1:Control.Monad.Catch.MonadThrow m1,
                         YesodAuth site) =>
                        (AuthRoute -> Route site) -> WidgetT site m1 ()
      at Yesod/Auth/Email.hs:(271,5)-(275,10)
    The type variable ‘m0’ is ambiguous
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance MonadIO m =>
               MonadIO
                 (conduit-1.2.6.1:Data.Conduit.Internal.Conduit.ConduitM i o m)
        -- Defined in ‘conduit-1.2.6.1:Data.Conduit.Internal.Conduit’
      instance MonadIO m =>
               MonadIO (conduit-1.2.6.1:Data.Conduit.Internal.Pipe.Pipe l i o u m)
        -- Defined in ‘conduit-1.2.6.1:Data.Conduit.Internal.Pipe’
      instance MonadIO IO -- Defined in ‘Control.Monad.IO.Class’
      ...plus 18 others
    In the first argument of ‘runFormPost’, namely ‘loginForm’
    In a stmt of a 'do' block:
      ((_, widget), enctype) <- runFormPost loginForm
    In the expression:
      do { ((_, widget), enctype) <- runFormPost loginForm;
           (do { (asWidgetT . toWidget)
                   ((Text.Blaze.Internal.preEscapedText . T.pack)
                      "<form method=\"post\" action=\"");
                 (getUrlRenderParams
                  >>=
                    (\ urender_ajDM
                       -> (asWidgetT . toWidget)
                            (toHtml (\ u_ajDN -> urender_ajDM u_ajDN ... (toParent loginR)))));
                 (asWidgetT . toWidget)
                   ((Text.Blaze.Internal.preEscapedText . T.pack) "\"></form>\n") }) }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain, but I think your `toWidget` call is your primary problem. Also, you'll need to lift your `runFormPost` from Handler to Widget, which can be done with `handlerToWidget`.

Comment: I think you were right, that definitely got me a bit closer. However, I'm still a bit baffled by the MonadIO error. I'll add the new error and code above. Also, why does that need to be lifted from a handler to a widget? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Why are you calling toWidget at all? What happens when you get rid of the call?

Comment: I was using toWidget because I was thinking that it would help Haskell deduce MonadIO m0. Perhaps that thinking was wrong. I've removed it and I'm adding the error above. The issue still seems to be deducing MonadIO m0.

Comment: That error message is GHC's way of saying "I can't tell what monad you're trying to run this in, so I'll call it `m0` and tell you I don't know if it's a `MonadIO`." The best way to debug from here is to start adding type signatures and see what happens.